# Calling a dialog function from an action bar item crashes Android app

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an action bar item that I would like to click which I set:

```
android:onClick="showDialog"
```

So I can call my show dialog function which works fine when called from a button on my activity_main.xml but not from my menu_main.xml. When I enter this code in menu_main.xml I get this small informational warning, -- Method "showDialog" in "MainActivity" has an incorrect signature.

As soon as the app opens up, it instantly crashes with a fatal exception:

*dialog.com.dialogtry1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler showDialog in class dialog.com.dialogtry1.MainActivity*

Here is my showDialog code in the MainActivity:

```
    public void showDialog(View v){
        FragmentManager Fmanager = getFragmentManager();
        Dialog myDialog = new Dialog();
        myDialog.show(Fmanager, "MyDialog");
}
```

Here is my Dialog class:

```
    public class Dialog extends DialogFragment{
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment, null);
    }
}
```

Here is my dialogfragment.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create new list."
    android:id="@+id/headerID"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="List name here."
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerID"
    android:id="@+id/editTextID"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yes"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextID"
    android:id="@+id/yesID"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No"
    android:id="@+id/noID"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextID"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yesID"/>
```

Comment: copy&paste your code for displaying menu here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.. when I removed (View v) as an arguement from my showDialog function, I was able to use OnOptionsItemSelected with no "method not resolvable" errors. The link you posted will definitely help me for the future, thats a lot of good stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
android:onClick="showDialog"
```

try using [`onOptionsItemSelected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu). `onOptionsItemSelected` is the correct way to handle click events in menu items.

Comment: When I call showDialog() it says it cannot resolve the method

Comment: I found the issue.. when I removed (View v) as an arguement from my showDialog function, I was able to use OnOptionsItemSelected with no "method not resolvable" errors.

The link you posted will definitely help me for the future, thats a lot of good stuff.

Thanks!